# Android application crash after using action_view intent

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a strange error , Here's my code

```
String a;
String b;
a="http://website1.com/abcabc1";
String[] separated = a.split("/");
b = separated[3];

String url = "www.website2.com/" + b;
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

What I want to do is getting the the value after .com/" in string a "which is abcabc1" and then open a new url which will be "www.website2.com/abcabc1" but the problem I have is the application crashes upon launch . I tried to discover the source of the problem and what i found was that if my code was :

```
String url = "www.website2.com/";
```

It will work without any problem , but if it was like this :

```
String url = "www.website2.com/" + b;
```

Application will crash .

Note If I try to set string url as textview text it shows it in the correct form but if i pass it to browser it crashes . Sorry for my poor language and thanks in advance .

Update :
Catlog :

```
04-01 14:09:08.670: D/AndroidRuntime(2126): Shutting down VM
04-01 14:09:08.670: W/dalvikvm(2126): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ad7ba8)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126): Process: com.example.ytdownload, PID: 2126
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ytdownload/com.example.ytdownload.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=www.youtube-mp3.org/?e=session_expired&tx }
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=www.youtube-mp3.org/?e=session_expired&tx }
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at com.example.ytdownload.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-01 14:09:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu I've added it to the question .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must set `"http://"` before your url, and it'll work!

`String url = "http://www.website2.com/" + b;`

Comment: It works now ! I can't believe that I forgot this part ! Thank you very much

Comment: @user3472788 Don't forget to check this as a correct answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I may make a suggestion, following the same problem (took me HOURS to figure out!!) - I now add the following code snippet (especially for cases in which I ask a user for a url, but it seems like a good idea even for cases where I myself supply it, because I tend to forget it myself):

```
if (!(websiteString.contains("http://"))) {
            websiteString = "http://" + websiteString;
        }
```

`websitString` is of course the string containing the entered URL. 
Hop this helps :)
P.S - if this is bad programming practice I would appreciate it if people commented on it. I'm very new at this!